# phantomjs output file size: png v gif

Tags: phantomjs, png, transparency, opacity, gif

With [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) you can choose the file format to use for [`page.render()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html).

I'm finding that the file size I'm getting for png is around three times higher than what I'm getting for gif.  I wasn't aware that png should be any worse (in terms of file size) than gif; in fact I thought png was meant to be better.

Unfortunately, I kinda need to output to png because of its support for variable opacity, but the larger file size is a bit of an issue.

So, is there any way in which I can control file size of the png?  Maybe change the encoding scheme or something?  I'm currently using phantomjs 1.9.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Inside of PhantomJS

**No**, there is no way to make the png file size smaller, but there is a way to make it bigger (*just for fun*):

1. Render the file to png,
2. load the file to a canvas of appropriate size,
3. get the Data-URI of the canvas in png or any other format,
4. decode the Base 64 part and write to file (this is very tricky to get right).

PhantomJS 1.x has a bug which results in a vastly inflated, but valid file.

Only jpeg rendering enables you to specify a quality setting which will result in a smaller file size, but then again jpeg doesn't support transparency.

You could also see whether PhantomJS 2.0.0 behaves better, because it has an engine underneath it that is almost three years newer than in PhantomJS 1.x.

#### Outside of PhantomJS

Your best bet would be to render the png in PhantomJS as-is and post-process it with your favorite library. It may even be enough to open it and save it again.

You can for example call an installed program with the child process module or your can open a webpage that contains such a service and upload the captured file or base64 representation of it. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I tried PhantomJS 2.0.0 but the size of the png was even bigger... so I'm sticking with 1.9.8!  Looks like post-processing is the only option, then.  I'm now just running the output through ImageMagick (basically converting png to png, but with the ability to control compression).  That reduces the size a bit compared to the standard phantomjs png output (e.g. 95KB to 78KB).

Comment: I voted a down a few hours ago because I don't think the answer helpful as I read "just for fun". Since I'm looking for a way to make the file smaller, it's hard to convince me that this is fun. However, I took back the vote. I am afraid I shouldn't just be so mean.And maybe it's making you uncomfortable. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo The exact question in this post is *"I can control file size of the png"*, so increasing the file size is also a way to controlling it (sort of). It's just a *fun* (for me at least) way of using a bug in PhantomJS. I hope I made it clearer that it's not possible to reduce the file size only with the capabilities of PhantomJS. The only way would be to use an external tool or web service to post-process it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. According to the context from the author ` I'm getting for png is around three times higher than what I'm getting for gif` I am sure he wants to reduce the size not just `control` it. But thanks for pointing out that this has nothing to do with phantomjs. And that would save me time to find non-existed solutions. So I finally upvoted you :)