# Is there anyway to make the screen snap image compressed with phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs, png

phantomjs has a very cool feature to capture some area of the screen of a page. But the output PNG file is too big by default.

Is there anyway to make it smaller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phantomjs output file size: png v gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017497/phantomjs-output-file-size-png-v-gif)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes. I've left you a message there.